# retrieving values from array objects

Tags: java, arrays, object

First of all am new to java.

below program is based on a shop, creating my own program which i face in my own shop.

program is running perfectly but i have problem in retrieving values from an array

## this is object

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class bale
{
   static int pieces;
   static int BaleCost = 0;
   static int singlepiece;

   public bale()
   {
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      pieces = in.nextInt(); 
      System.out.print("Enter the Single Piece price: ");
      singlepiece = in.nextInt();
      BaleCost = singlepiece*pieces;
   }


}
```

## this is main program

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class ShopProfit
{
   static bale[] bales;//creating bales array
   static int TotalBaleAmount;
   static int n;
   static int totalpieces = 0;




   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      bales();  
      System.out.println("There are "+totalpieces+" pieces in "+n+" bales"); 
      System.out.println("you have to pay "+TotalBaleAmount+" rupees to the bale company");

      for(int i = 0; i<=n-1; i++)
      {
         System.out.println("bale "+(i+1)+" has "+bales[i].pieces+" with "+bales[i].singlepiece+" rupess per picece");

      }

   }


   static void bales()
   {

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("Enter the number of bales you bought: ");
      n = in.nextInt();
      bales = new bale[n];
      for(int i = 0; i<=n-1; i++)
      {
         System.out.print("Enter the number of pieces in bale"+(i+1)+": ");
         bales[i] = new bale();


         totalpieces = totalpieces + bale.pieces;
         TotalBaleAmount = TotalBaleAmount + bale.BaleCost;



      }


   }    


}
```

## input and output

Enter the number of bales you bought: 3

Enter the number of pieces in bale1: 300

Enter the Single Piece price: 92

Enter the number of pieces in bale2: 240

Enter the Single Piece price: 85

Enter the number of pieces in bale3: 350

Enter the Single Piece price: 96

There are 890 pieces in 3 bales

you have to pay 81600 rupees to the bale company

bale 1 has 350 with 96 rupess per picece

bale 2 has 350 with 96 rupess per picece

bale 3 has 350 with 96 rupess per picece

#### You can See last three lines in the output, i need exact answers which i have given as input but program executed  final input values only.

#### please help me to retrieve array value as per given input.

Comment: Remove static from the class member definitions in the bale class.

Comment: You have both a member variable and a method with the name bales. That could get confusing fast. Also, the above comment is correct, static means to make only 1 copy of a variable for every instance of a class. You want different variables for each instance so just remove static and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is Your BaleCost in Bale is static so you are always setting the cost to the same variable. 
But the real problem is that the design is not object oriented at all.

Try creating a factory for create the Bale's and use Bale just as a POJO to store the data.

HIH,
Bargas

Comment: your answer is probably fine but a beginner might have hard time understanding concepts of factory and POJO's